# Fabric says 'no route to host', even though I can access it over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm having some issues uploading a file to a server with Fabric. I get the following output:

```
Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host ssh.example.com: No route to host

Aborting.
```

The weird thing is, when I connect manually using `ssh` (same host string, I copy-pasted it from the fabfile to make sure), it works perfectly as expected. I can also use `scp` to copy the file to the same location manually.

The offending line in my Fabfile is this, if it helps:

```
put('media.tgz','/home/private/media.tgz')
```

Also, I'm connecting to a different host to the rest of my fabfile using the `@hosts()` decorator (this particular method uploads static media, which is served from somewhere different to the app itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. Had not investigated it but using the IP-Address instead the hostname helped. This particular host had an IPv6 AAAA record but my client had no IPv6 connection, maybe this is the reason. HTH

Comment: I've had the same issue and it is related to using AAAA records when you have no ipv6 connectivity